# JMSContext NullPointer Exception - wildfly 8.2.0 default queue

Tags: jms, wildfly-8

I am trying to send messages to my default queue in wildfly and when i invoke "sendMessage()"  the JMSContext is giving me a null pointer exception. what can i fix ?

```
public class SendMsg {


@Resource(lookup = "java:/ConnectionFactory")
 ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;


JMSContext context=connectionFactory.createContext();

@Resource(mappedName="java:/jms/queue/test")
Queue queue;

public void sendMessage(String message) {
    System.out.println("fancy beans");
    context.createProducer().send(queue, message);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled over this same error (in my case, I was trying to inject a JMSContext into a Servlet).

It was a missing `beans.xml` file. In my case, it belonged in the WEB-INF folder of the war file. Apparently the Weld subsystem is only started when it is present: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Developer+Guide#DeveloperGuide-Whicharetheimplicitmoduledependencies%3F

Although I suspect that it's started in other circumstances as well - I have an EJB application which doesnt need any `bean.xml` for CDI to work.

Answer (score 0):

You cant call the connection factory that "early". It will not be injected during the construction of your bean. Inject a JMSContext directly is probably easier.

```
public class SendMsg {


//@Resource(lookup = "java:/ConnectionFactory")
//ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

@Inject
JMSContext context;   //=connectionFactory.createContext();
```